# MySQL Category Hierarchy Search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a category tree with limitless sub-categories and products. I want to search products of a category including the ones in sub-categories of selected cat.

P.S. I'm open to PHP solutions.

Here's my tables.

```
`cat` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

`product` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested Sets are a pretty standard way of doing this
http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/
(a random result found from a google search for "nested set mysql php")

You batch compute a few extra columns on your category table, then makes queries for all 'sub-categories' (and sub-sub-categories etc :) easy.

Comment: Be warned that nested structures are a huge pain to to work with if you are using a SQL database.

Comment: Kinda vague, whats painful about them? For me at least they work just fine.

Comment: Insertion and Deletion is painful.

Comment: deletion is easy if the there are no children of the deleted node. Just remove it. If there is children, you do need to recompute at least part of the tree.  - anyway whats your alternative suggestion to avoid using them?